# There is a compilation error in my PL/SQL code

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a compilation error in my PL/SQL code, The audit_client table will be updated if any update or delete occurs on client_master

```
create or replace trigger t1
after update or delete on client_master
for each row

DECLARE
v1 varchar2(10);
v2 varchar2(80);
v3 number(11);
oper varchar2(15);
BEGIN
v1:= :old.CLIENT_NO
v2:= :old.NAME
v3:= :old.BALANCE
if updating then
    oper:='update'
    insert into audit_client values(v1,v2,v3,oper,v4,v5);
    end if;
if deleting then
    oper:='delete'
    insert into audit_client values(v1,v2,v3,oper,v4,v5);
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the compilation error you are getting.  There are several possible errors that your code could generate, we don't want to guess at what compilation errors you are getting because we might get it wrong and provide an unhelpful answer to you.

Comment: The assignments to `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are missing their terminating semicolons. The insert into the audit table refers to variables `v4` and `v5` that don't seem to be declared.

Comment: Shouldn't you capture the **new** values on update?

Comment: Client_master attributes - client_number, name , balance , address , city. Audit_client attributes- client_number , name , balance , operation , user_id, operation_date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you declare those `v` variables at all? Somewhat simplified:

```
create or replace trigger t1
  after update or delete on client_master
  for each row
declare
  l_oper varchar2(15);
begin
  if updating then 
     l_oper := 'update';
  elsif deleting then
     l_oper := 'delete';
  end if;
  
  insert into audit_client 
    (client_no, name, balance, oper, col4, col5)
  values
    (:old.client_no, :old.name, :old.balance, l_oper, null, null);
end;
/
```

Instead of `v4` and `v5` I inserted `NULL` as you never said what should be put in there.

Also, as a good practice, you should *always* specify column list you're working with. That's why I made up those column names as I don't know their real names, but you do and you should use them.

Comment: V4, V5 are User_id and operation_date

Comment: OK, include them into the INSERT statement.